# Poor Response.Output.Write performance with Internet Explorer 9 on Windows 7

Tags: .net, iis-7, internet-explorer-9

We have a ASP .NET web server that sits on IIS7.  In order for our server to be able to transfer large files (let's say 30-50MB) to the web client, we implemented the Response.Output.Write algorithm as found here: http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=812406.

Here's a snippet of our code:

```
long offset = 0, cb = info.AudioStream.Length;

context.Response.Clear();
context.Response.ClearHeaders();
context.Response.ContentType = "audio/wav";
context.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", cb.ToString());
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + info.RecordingId + ".wav");

context.Response.Buffer = false;
context.Response.BufferOutput = false;
context.Response.Flush();

info.AudioStream.Seek(offset, SeekOrigin.Begin);

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];

long total = 0;
int count;
Tracer.TraceInfo(true, "WaveHandler::ProcessRequest; Before loop.");

while (context.Response.IsClientConnected && 
    total < cb && 
    (count = info.AudioStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)Math.Min(buffer.Length, cb - total))) != 0)
{
    Tracer.TraceInfo(true, "WaveHandler::ProcessRequest; Before 'Write'; Count: " + count);

    context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);

    Tracer.TraceInfo(true, "WaveHandler::ProcessRequest; After 'Write'; Total: " + total);

    total += count;
}

Tracer.TraceInfo(true, "WaveHandler::ProcessRequest; After loop.");

context.Response.Flush();
```

The problem is that from the same Windows 7 client PC, transferring a ~35MB file when using firefox 15.0 takes 5 seconds but the same operation with IE9 takes ~3m30s.  On another XP client PC with IE8, it takes 10 seconds to transfer the same ~35MB file.

We tried to play with the transmit buffer size (from 4kB to 1MB) or to put a 'Response.Flush()' inside the loop but we always have the same poor performance with IE9.

We don't know which end needs tweaking: the web server side or the client side?

**Update:**
The client's web page is used to playback the transmitted audio file. The difference between IE and Firefox is that Windows Media Player (embedded) is used for playback in IE and an audio tag is used when != IE. Could it be that WMP is throttling the file transfer?

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Why not let the browser handle the download by simply redirecting to the file or using `Response.WriteFile()`?

Comment: @Shadow - The call to 'WriteFile' itself is fast, but the time that it takes to transfer the file to the client is the same.

Comment: Same like what? I don't think you can improve the time, as far as I can tell it's all handled by the browser and depend on the connection speed as well. I would say that IE9 simply handles this poorly - nothing surprising here. :)

Comment: @Shadow - The same as when the 'OutputStream.Write' loop is used. I guess that the answer is 'by design' and that we'll have to implement real file streaming instead of the file transfer that we currently have.